# Trying to find index of minimum value in a list of vars in Octave

Tags: octave, octave-gui

I have a list of vars with different values

```
a = 2
b = 1
c= 12343243
d = 8998
```

Can find the smallest value

```
aSmallestVALUE = min([a, b, c, d])
```

and index

```
[v,idx]=min([a, b, c, d])
```

I want to find the index of variable and sort this list from 0 to up
something like the

```
sorted list = b, a, d, c
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the index of [the] variable"? You have already found the index of the smallest value in the vector `[a, b, c, d]`. To sort that vector you could use the `sort()` function. What is the objective you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously if you want to treat those four variables as a 'list' to be sorted, you need to be working with a 'list' construct, not 4 isolated variables.

```
L = [2, 1, 12343243, 8998];
```

Otherwise it makes no sense to talk about the 'index' of an existing independent variable (though obviously you can construct this `L` from a bunch of pre-existing variables if desired).

With `L` in hand, you can now do

```
[minval, idx] = min( L )
% minval = 1
% idx = 2
```

to find the minimum and its corresponding index, and

```
[sorted, sortedindices] = sort( L )
% sorted =
%    1.0000e+00   2.0000e+00   8.9980e+03   1.2343e+07
%
% sortedindices =
%    2   1   4   3
```

to obtain a sorted array, with corresponding indices.